# Using type parameter from class declaration like reified type parameter in function

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance

I want to write a function, which needs to use a the class representation of a class declaration like `MyClass::class.java`.

I have a base class `ActivityStarter` which I use as a base for companion objects in activities.

```
// declarations
open class ActivityCompanion<T: AppCompatActivity>(val activityClass : Class<T>) {
    fun startActivity(context: Context) {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, activityClass))
    }
}

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object : ActivityStarter<MyActivity>(MyActivity::class:java)
...
}

// call
MyActivity.startActivity(this)
```

In the declaration, and the inheritence of the companion object, the class is basically passed twice. Once as type parameter and once as normal parameter. (`ActivityStarter<MyActivity>(MyActivity::class:java)`).

The parameter `activityClass` is necessary, because I cant use `T::class.java`. "Cannot use T as reified type parameter. Use class instead".

I have used to just pass the parameter in the function call:

```
// declarations
open class ActivityStarter {
    inline fun <reified T : AppCompatActivity>startActivity(context: Context) {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, T::class.java))
    }
}

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object : ActivityStarter()
...
}

// call
MyActivity.startActivity<MyActivity>(this)
```

This removes the redundancy from the companion object declaration but puts it into the call and basically makes the type parameter in the class useless.

Is there a way to make the type parameter used in the class declaration `reified`, so that I can have an implementation like this?:

```
// declarations
open class ActivityCompanion<reified T: AppCompatActivity>() {
    fun startActivity(context: Context) {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, T::class.java))
    }
}

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object : ActivityStarter<MyActivity>()
...
}

// call
MyActivity.startActivity(this)
```

Or another way to resctict the activityClass parameter so that I can have something like this:

```
// declarations
open class ActivityStarter(private val activityClass : Class<T : AppCompatActivity>) {
    inline fun startActivity(context: Context) {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, activityClass))
    }
}

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object : ActivityStarter(MyActivity::class.java)
...
}

// call
MyActivity.startActivity(this)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the type parameter used in the class declaration reified

No. But what if you make `startActivity` not a member of `ActivityCompanion`, but an extension function so it *can* have reified type parameters?

```
class ActivityCompanion<T: AppCompatActivity>()

fun <reified T: AppCompatActivity> ActivityCompanion<T>.startActivity(context: Context) {
    context.startActivity(Intent(context, T::class.java))
}

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object : ActivityStarter<MyActivity>()
    ...
}

MyActivity.startActivity(this)
```

> Or another way to resctict the activityClass parameter so that I can have something like this:

If I understood correctly and you want `ActivityStarter` to accept any subclass of `AppCompatActivity` without having a type parameter itself, you can write it as

```
open class ActivityStarter(protected val activityClass: Class<out AppCompatActivity>) { ... }
```

See [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) or [What is out keyword in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298702/what-is-out-keyword-in-kotlin) for the meaning of `out`.

Comment: Already thought about that, but I would have liked a more uniform solution. Some of my activities use values, which I pass as parameters in startActivity, so that I can hide the whole intent build up and break down within the activity.

Comment: Then maybe the alternative in the edited answer will work for you.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Now when I use this, I only have to pass the Activity Class once when I let a companion object inherit from it. Beautiful!